# API which returns all the GCP regions and availability zones

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am working on a project which requires me to list out all the Azure and GCP cloud's availability regions, is there any API or endpoint to make a call to fetch them all. Not looking for CLI commands.

Answer (score 1):

For GCP the endpoint is:

`https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/regions`

Replace `{project}` with your Project ID (not Project Name).

Documentation:

[Method: regions.list](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/regions/list)

There are also a number of SDKs for popular languages:

[Google Cloud SDK home page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk)

Example:

[API Documentation for listing regions using Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/google.cloud.compute_v1.services.regions)

Answer (score 0):

For Azure the API is

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/locations?api-version=2020-01-01
```

https://learn.microsoft.com//rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list-locations